# Why can't the PHP debugger find this object change?

Tags: php, object, debugging, properties

I am trying to track down where a change to a PHP object takes place, and the debugger is unable to step into the code where it happens.

I am tracing through a constructor with three assignments.

```
  public function __construct(DataDefinitionInterface $definition, $name = NULL, TypedDataInterface $parent = NULL) {
    $this->definition = $definition;
    $this->parent = $parent;
    $this->name = $name;
  }
```

After the second of those three assignments is done, a fourth property (defined by another class in the hierarchy) has changed from an empty array to an array with a single element. The object has magic getters and setters, but they don't get invoked here. The debugger won't step into the assignment to the `parent` property, and it won't hit the breakpoint on `__set()`. This last bit is appropriate, because those magic methods only kick in for properties which are undeclared or inaccessible, and the `parent` property is declared as `protected` above the constructor, and the object always has access to its own properties. In those cases (elsewhere in the software) in which a magic method (an "override" in the quaint language of the PHP documentation) *is* invoked, the debugger happily steps right in.

How is it possible that the debugger is unable to step into a statement which is clearly doing more work than a simple assignment?

I am running PHP 7.2.10 under Apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu 18.04.1, debugging in VSCode 1.33.1 with Xdebug 2.6.0. The code being debugged is from Drupal 8.7.0-dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in VSCode.

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/355

Just goes to show, you can't always trust the debugger.

Debugging using PhpStorm instead of VSCode was the solution.